# java method reading file and returning avg

Tags: java, file

I'm writing a public static method called fileAverage that takes a String that is the absolute path to a file.  The file is a simple text file with real numbers.  I need to handle the file with a try catch.  my catch block should print out info about the exception and my method shouldn't throw the exception.  my method them should return a double that is an average of the file.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Problem2 {

    public static final String filePath = "/Users/rderickson9/Desktop/CS2/fileAverage.txt";

    public static double fileAverage(String filePath){
        int total = 0;
        double fin = 0.0;
        double avg = 0;

        File file = new File(filePath);
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            while(true){
                String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
                if(nextLine.equals("")){
                    break;
                }
                double doubleTemp = Double.parseDouble(nextLine);
                fin = fin + doubleTemp;

                total++; 
            }
            avg = (fin/total);
            System.out.println(avg);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Problem2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


        return avg;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fileAverage(filePath);

    }
}
```

I'm not really following how to set this up so my method will run

example of file

```
3.2
4.7
2003
2.3
25
```

Comment: If you have Java 7 or 8, consider using `try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {...}` to have the file closed in the end.

Comment: So...what's not working?

Answer (score 1):

You can directly fetch out double from a file using `Scanner class` like this

```
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
 double doubleTemp = sc.nextDouble();
 fin += doubleTemp; //short hand operator
  total++; 
 }
avg = (fin/total);
System.out.println(avg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java 8 solution:

```
List<String> l = new LinkedList<>();
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(file)) {
   sc.useDelimiter("\\v").forEachRemaining(l::add);        
   l.stream().mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).average().ifPresent(System.out::println);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```